# How to get x axis ticks closer to axis in jqPlot?

Tags: alignment, jqplot

I'm new to jqPlot and decided to try it out.

I'm facing an issue which I cannot resolve.

[image]

The ticks for month ('Jul' etc.) are too far below the x-axis. Is there a way to bring the ticks closer to the axis?

The options for the axes are as follows:

```
axesDefaults: {
            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer, 
                    tickOptions: {
                        size: 2
                    }},
                ticks: ticks,
                label: xAxisTitle,
                min: 0
            },
            yaxis: {
                label: yAxisTitle,
                pad: 1.05
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, ticks are close to the graph.

It should be a container size problem. Try to reduce it, move your label (perhaps inside your table see [legend location](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#Legend.location))

[Tick documentation](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-axisTickRenderer-js.html#%24.jqplot.AxisTickRenderer)